# How can I find frequently changing files in a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, refactoring

I'm jumping into a new code base with the intention of making it more stable.  What I am struggling to determine though is where most of the turbulence is in the code.

I'm looking for a way that I can find which files within the repository are most frequently being changed so that I can come up with a starting point for some refactoring.  It doesn't appear that there is a built-in Mercurial command for this, and Google doesn't seem to have much to offer either (or I'm using the wrong terms.)

At the moment all that comes to mind would be to write a script that would parse the 'files:' line from the `hg log -v` command and count the files manually.  This will work, but I'd be awfully surprised if I'm the first person that has had to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
 hg log --template "{files % '{file}\n'}" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
     21 templates/base.html
     19 TODO
      8 content/about.rst
      6 static/screen.css
```

That shows 21 chngesets touch `templates/base.html`, the most of my tiny repo.

Comment: Template only for rather fresh Mercurial

Comment: I'd be curious to know what version of Mercurial you're running this with, and on which OS?

Comment: Yeah, I'm running 2.5.  I'll put in a soln that works for older mercurials.

Comment: I chose this as the correct answer because while it only works on recently updated Mercurial installs currently, it is more likely in the future to work for others as they update their Mercurial installs over time.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to move by opposite way

1. Get list of files
2. For every file from p.1 execute something like `hg log FILENAME --template "+" | wc -m`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that works with older Mercurial installs:

```
$ hg grep --files-with-matches --all . | cut -d : -f 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
 21 templates/base.html
 19 TODO
  8 content/about.rst
  6 static/screen.css
```

If you have colons in your filename you'll need to add `--print0` and change the `cut` invocation too.

Comment: `hg locate` will be simpler, than grep, with the same result. Or `hg manifest` (and without cut in both cases)

Comment: I believe that with `locate` you'd have to loop across all revisions manually since it lacks `--all` and that with `manifest` the `--all` option de-duplicates the files so you'd not get a count of how many revisions each one showed up in.  Can you show the `locate` or `manifest` solution to count which files are modified in the greatest number of changesets?